# Error:(26, 36) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save data using SharedPrefrences but I am getting this error:

Error:(26, 36) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()

Do I need to import something?

Here is my java file:

```
package test.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
        getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

/**@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}**/
}
```

Comment: Apart from the answers below, the call to `getActivity` is not even in a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to do this:

```
Context context = getActivity();
```

An `Activity` *is* a context.

Just do:

```
Context context = this;
```

Or just:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences(
    getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Or even just:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
    getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Now it is saying: Error:(27, 31) error: cannot find symbol variable preference_file_key. Sorry for being such a noob, but what do I do here?

Comment: Now I am really confused. Because I got 3 downvotes I cannot ask another question?

Comment: Sorta late but you probably got downvoted because the qualifications for downvoting are: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." Typically the assumption is that users do research to try and find their own problem, then if they can't, post a clear question that can help future users.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `getActivity()` inside an Activity, just use `this` or skip it altogether and call `getSharedPreferences`

Comment: Sorry I meant for whoever downvoted your answer to explain why they did so, but they seem to have taken it back.